# How to Query Curl in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to create the below CURL post request. I don't quite understand how to create it in PHP. Any help is appreciated.

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[AccountSID]/Messages.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=[PhoneNumber]' \
--data-urlencode 'From=[PhoneNumber]' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=[Message]' \
-u [AccountSID]:[AuthToken]
```

This is what I tried, but was unsuccessful:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_url.$path);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$this->acct_sid.":".$this->authToken);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$fields = array("To"=>$to,
"From"=>$this->from_number,
"Body"=>$msg);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($fields));

curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: use [`curl_error`](http://php.net/curl_error) to check what's the error

Answer (score 0):

Here the working code

```
$url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' . $sid . '/SMS/Messages';
$auth = $sid . ':' . $token;

$fields = 
    '&To=' .  urlencode( $to ) . 
    '&From=' . urlencode( $from ) . 
    '&Body=' . urlencode( $body );


$res = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_POST, 3 ); 
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth ); 
curl_setopt( $res, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 


$result = curl_exec( $res );
print_r($result);
```

This code works for me and remeber authentication must be the combination of **SID** and **token** both. not just token. and POST fields are **to**, **from**, **body**.